# Swift tableviewcell height stays fixed

Tags: swift, xcode, tableview

My tableviewcell height stays fixed even though I do the following:

```
tableView.rowHeight = UITableView.automaticDimension
tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 150
```

I have one imageview and one label inside the cell and I gave constraints to each side.

Also, I tried:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return UITableView.automaticDimension
}
```

I need a fixed height for my cell. It doesnt need to be dynamic. But no matter what i tried the height stays around 50px.

Any help?

Comment: post how you set constraints in cell here or a github demo

Comment: Comment out these codes and specify the desired height in `heightForRowAtIndexPath` delegate method, if you don't want the height to be dynamic.

Comment: ugh, think I tried too many things and got lost. I did as you said and I am able to increase the height now. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Setting `automaticDimension` is based on using auto layout in your cells.

This means you must add a `NSLayoutConstraint` to all sides of a `UILabel` (or any other control you use in your cells) and the `UITableViewCell` container in interface designer or in code. In case of a label, configure setting 'Lines' to 0 and 'Line Break' to Word Wrap.

Answer (score 1):

you can set the height you want with heightForRowAtIndexPath, hopefully that helps